# Change behavior of base64binary type tag validation

Tags: java, xml, spring, validation, soap

I have problem with validating XML that has tag with base="xsd:base64Binary". When I'm sending request with padded bas64, everything works, but with unpadded base64 I keep getting:

> 'x' is notvalid value for 'base64Binary'.

I debugged it myself and found out that validation is made by `handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint)` method in `AbstractValidatingInterceptor` of `org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor` package. `validator` is `Jaxp15ValidatorFactory$Jaxp15Validator` of `org.springframework.xml.validation` package, which calls `Validator` of `javax.xml.validation` package.

What is the best approach to change this behavior? For now I don't want to change wsdl and I want to keep all other validations in place. Important note: SAXExceptions are handled in my code and all of the validation errors are managed, so my problem is not that the request is failing. My problem is that this validation error is being delivered to my own validation handler. For my purposes the best solution will be to make it disappear before.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a base64 value which does not pass validation?

Answer (score 0):

The error message means what it says. Your content is not valid according to the XSD definition of Base64.

To get rid of the error message you either need to change the data or to change the schema.